# CiviRules Trigger:Contribution is Added not working for Online Payments

Tags: civirules

I've created several rules that assign a contact subtype to contacts depending on their level of donation.

The trigger I am using is "Contribution is added".

The rules function correctly if a contribution is added via the backend, but not when people make online payments through a donation page.

Is there a setting that would affect this? Is there a way to set up rules that will trigger by online payments?

Comment: I recently experienced this same issue. Can you tell me what version of CiviCRM and CiviRules you're running?

Answer (score 1):

I did a test with a completely new rule, and online payment correctly triggered the rule.

Comment: Did that solve the issue for you?